# Excel Value Replacement in Python

Tags: python

I do have some inquiry about looping in python specially using selenium.

I am having trouble on this scenario:

Example, I have 46 cells but 3 of them has values that i want to replace(e.g in [1,5],[14,5],[26,5]. This is the cell that I want to replace the value. I will name this as X

Now the values that i have is 3 and its on the bottom of **another** excel ([43,1],[44,1],[45,1]). I will name this as Y

So I want to pair this like Y1(Value) = X1(Value), Y2(Value) = X2(Value), Y3(Value) = X3(Value)

I want the result as this one : (**Expected Result**)

Y1[43,1] = X1[1,5], Y2[44,1] = X2[14,5], Y3[45,1] = X3[26,5]
but the **actual result:**

Y1 = X1, Y1 = X2, Y1 = X3.

My code is below: Sorry Newbie in Python

```
    excel_all_data = Instant.getRowCount(self, "..\\TestData\\TestData.xlsx", "TestData")

    for y in range(excel_all_data):

        data_to_read = Instant.readDataFile(self, "..\\TestData\\TestData.xlsx", "TestData", y + 1, 5)  # Read all Data with value of replace expected value is 3
        if data_to_read == "Replace":

            for pj in range(new_range):  # New Range is the value in the other excel which i pulled (3)
                bagong_data = Instant.readDataFile(self, csv_path_input, "csv_file", max_row - pj, 2)
                Instant.writeDataFile(self, "..\\TestData\\TestData.xlsx", "TestData", y + 1, 5, bagong_data)
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with Selenium. Can you elaborate about the expected and actual results? it's not really clear.

Comment: okay let me edit this again

Comment: So you have two csv files, one with a few values that need to be replaced and another with values that will will be replacing them?

Comment: I dont really understand what youre trying to achieve, but im thinking, using pandas library would be a lot easier

Comment: sorry bout that i really cant explain it properly. I do have values in 2 excel. in the first excel i want to copy the 3 values(different cells). i want to transfer that to the other excel by replacing it. The catch is it it has its on separated cells (but same column)

Comment: example: first excel A1 = ABC, A2 = BCD, A3 = CDE.
i want to transfer that in the second excel 
C1= ABC, C14 = BCD, C26 = CDE

but what happens is C1 = ABC, C14 = ABC, C26 = ABC

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand what you are trying to achieve here, as Mr.Riply suggests, we can use pandas to replace values in a table.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("file_with_vals_to_replace")

list_of_vals_to_replace = [1,2,3]

df['A'].replace( # assuing the column name is "A"
    to_replace=list_of_vals_to_replace,
    value='REPLACE',
    inplace=True
)

df.to_excel('new_file')
```

Comment: Thank you. Tried this but still the same. Sorry about my question. But to clarify i do have 2 excel. excel1 and excel2. 
In excel1 the last 3 data which is A43, A44, A45 is the data i need. I want to transfer that in excel2. (manage to do that)

I want a43, to be in excel2 D0, A44 in D12, A45 in D26. The catch is D0, D12, D26 are the only values the rest on that column has no data